# String operator convert into usable type in PHP if statement

Tags: php, string

In my code I get the conditional operator as a String.

```
">=","<=","<",">"
```

How can i use this operator in php if statement?. is it possible to convert that?.

Comment: Without using `eval` you'd probably have to do something like `if ($operator === '>=' && $yourVar >= $yourComparison)`...

Comment: Look at the switch statement example and return a conditional from the switch statement

Comment: can you send me a link?.

Comment: you just got a link at top by @Hanky